# Issue to Get data from two dimentional json

Tags: javascript, json

i have a nested json which give me error.

JSON:

```
[{"id":"15",
  "rand_key":"",
  "landlord_name":"Shah",
  "property_req_1":{
    "lead_req_id":"",
    "lead_id":"0",
    "category_id":"1",
    "region_id":"1",
    "area_location_id":"17",
    "sub_area_location_id":"3447",
    "min_beds":"1",
    "max_beds":"",
    "min_budget":"3332",
    "max_budget":"0",
    "min_area":"",
    "max_area":"0",
    "unit_type":"2",
    "unit_no":"",
    "listing_id_1_ref":"RH-R-17",
    "listing_id_1":"17"
  }
}]
```

Code:

```
var json=null;
$.getJSON("ajax_files/getSingleRow_leads.php?id="+id, function(json){ 
    json = json[0];
```

here `alert(json.property_req_1);` give me `[object Object]`

```
    if(json.property_req_1){

        var getReq = jQuery.parseJSON('['+json.property_req_1+']');
        $.each(getReq, function(id, key) {
```

can not get it here

```
        });
    }
});
```

what i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var firstData = json[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < json.property_req_1.length; j++) {
        var data = json.property_req_1[j];        
    }
}
```

Comment: these two alerts give me undefined..alert(firstData.property_req_1.length);
 alert(json.property_req_1.length);